# What is the relationship between the words debtor and debitor?

Tags: synonyms, connotation

My question is - "are there any differences between the meanings, connotations and usages of the words debtor and debitor?". The context in which I intend to use the word is a business budget, where it is used as an antonym to the word "creditor"; I wish to find the most appropriate word for this context.

My instinct would be to use debitor where referring to a party who owes a debt to another specified party, and to use debtor to denote a party which is in a state of debt e.g.:

- "Purchaser A is debitor to supplier B"
- "Mr. C is a debtor, and urgently needs to turn his financial state around"

This would make debitor the more appropriate word for my usage. [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/debitor) appears to support the use of "debitor" in this way. However, debtor can also be used to mean a party which owes a debt to another specific party. So is my instinct correct in this case?

Secondly my text editing software flags debitor as a misspelling, and Collins states that the word is used rarely. Is the word debitor so rare as to be likely to be taken as a misspelling, or seen as an anachronism?

Comment: You know that Collins say it is rarely used; what do *other* dictionaries say?

Comment: Merriam-Webster and Dictionary.com say "obsolete"; Oxford and Cambridge on-line don't seem to list it. Wordnet lists it as an alternate form of debtor, but as far as I know doesn't include details on how widespread it may be.

Comment: So you have two 'obsoletes', a 'rarely used' and two significant dictionaries don't choose to include it in their their free-access online versions . Does that get you closer to answering your question?

Comment: I would say it's the same as the relationship between "debt" and "debit".

Comment: To summarize, we are saying use one for all purposes and use the other never.

Comment: Thanks, Spagirl and Yosef Baskin your comments are helpful, they address half of my question; whether the word debitor is too obscure/obsolete to be usefully used, though they don't address the issue of weather the words are exact or inexact synonyms.

Comment: Hot Licks, do you have any evidence for that? I would instinctively have agreed with you, but as debitor seems to be rare to obsolete I suspect it may just be a variant form of debtor.

Comment: It **is** a variant form of _debtor_, just as _debt_ is a variant form of _debit_. _Debit_ means 'he owes' in Latin and that's the meaning of _debt_. One's just become more specialized in English, that's all.

Comment: **debitor**: a person who owes a creditor; someone who has the obligation of paying a debt. Synonyms: **debtor**. https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/debitor

Comment: The archaic definition of "debit" is just that.  As Brillig explains, it now has a relatively specific meaning in accounting (at least in the US).  (And the terminology is "exposed" in bank statements, et al, read by "normal people", so it's generally understood.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Professor John Lawler wrote in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400313/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-words-debtor-and-debitor#comment951115_400313):

> *Debitor* **is** a variant form of *debtor*, just as *debt* is a variant form of *debit*. *Debit* means 'he owes' in Latin and that's the meaning of *debt*. One's just become more specialized in English, that's all.

Also, some dictionaries seem to support that they're variants: [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/debitor), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/debtor), [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/debitor).

Here's [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=debtor%2C%20debitor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdebtor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdebitor%3B%2Cc0) showing *debitor* going out of use:

[image: debitor vs debtor]

Comment: I find this answer particularly helpful for dealing with what is probably the root of my confusion -debt and debit were equivalent, but have diverged, while debtor and debitor were equivalent, but debitor has simply gone out of use.

Answer (score 3):

You mention that you are planning to use this for a business budget.  I have heard it said that *the language of business is accounting* and I believe most business people will be familiar with terminology from modern *double-entry accounting.*  The uses of *creditor* for *lender* and *debitor* for *debtor* harken back to the days of *single-entry accounting* when one would simply record a single entry of a loan made as a credit and a single entry of a loan received as a debit.  Today, with *double-entry accounting*, a loan made causes cash to be credited and accounts receivable or similar to be debited, while a loan received causes cash to be debited and loan payable or similar to be credited.  Thus, there is both a debit and credit entry in both cases.

That is why *debitor* has already begun to slip out of the language in this historic usage (and, who know?, *creditor* may one day follow).  There is not a difference in how *debtor* and *debitor* were used historically but today there is a difference, especially because *debitor* can be confusing given the rise of double-entry accounting and the pervasiveness of *debit cards* - a person using a debit card could be referred to as a *debitor* but that is a person who is avoiding owing a loan by paying directly from his bank account rather than using a *credit card*.

You can use *debtor* (or *loan payable*) for someone who has a loan and *delinquent* or *behind in payments* for someone in a more serious situation - *doubtful account* is the normal accounting terminology and a group of business people will likely all understand that term.

Instead of *creditor* the precise accounting term would be *loan receivable* although either should be understandable.

Comment: I like your explanation of why creditor and debitor could be confusing words to use to describe parties with which one does business. I think actually "customer" and "supplier" accounts are the word pair I should use, both of which could either be in debt or in credit. My original word choice was actually making an unhelpful assumption.